# ompl planning attempts to move through static obstacles

Tags: ros, ompl, ompl-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I'm trying to use the ompl planner to get the path for our robotic arm.  I have added static obstacles to the collision space, and sometimes when trying to move the arm from one location to another, as seen with rviz, the planned motion will attempt to move the hand at the end of the arm through the obstacles (in this case a table).....I have added the hand to the collision checks, as well as attempting to increase padding. I have also tried using various configurations (SBLk, LBKPIECEk, RRTConnect) but they all have the same result.

The output reports no errors in planning, so I dont understand why the motion doesn't avoid the obstacles....

Here are the settings used in collision_checks.yaml:

```
    default_collision_operations:
      - object1: platform
        object2: arm
        operation: enable

  - object1: torso
    object2: arm
    operation: enable
    
  - object1: tablet
    object2: arm
    operation: enable
    
  - object1: base_link
    object2: arm_0_link
    operation: disable    
    
  - object1: platform
    object2: hand
    operation: enable
    
  - object1: torso
    object2: hand
    operation: enable
    
  - object1: tablet
    object2: hand
    operation: enable    
    
  - object1: arm
    object2: hand
    operation: enable
    
  - object1: sdh_palm_link
    object2: arm_7_link
    operation: disable

  - object1: sdh_palm_link
    object2: arm_6_link
    operation: disable
  
  - object1: hand
    object2: arm_5_link
    operation: disable
```

Also, here are the ompl_planning_config.yaml settings:

```
groups: 
  - arm
arm:
  planner_type: JointPlanner
  planner_configs:
#    - SBLkConfig1 
#    - LBKPIECEkConfig1
     - RRTConnectConfig1

  kinematics_solver: pr2_arm_kinematics/PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin
  tip_name: arm_7_link
  root_name: arm_0_link
  robot: cob3-3
  projection_evaluator: joint_state
      
planner_configs:
  SBLkConfig1:
    type: kinematic::SBL

  LBKPIECEkConfig1:
    type: kinematic::LBKPIECE
    
  RRTConnectConfig1:
    type: kinematic::RRTConnect
    
publish_diagnostics: true
```

And finally, the planning_groups.yaml:

```
groups:

  - name: platform
    joints:
      base_joint
    links:
      base_link
      base_laser_front_link
      base_laser_rear_link
      base_laser_top_link      

  - name: torso
    joints:
      torso_lower_neck_pan_joint
      torso_lower_neck_tilt_joint
      torso_upper_neck_pan_joint
      torso_upper_neck_tilt_joint
    links:
      torso_lower_neck_tilt_link
      torso_upper_neck_tilt_link
      head_cover_link
      
  - name: tablet
    joints:
      torso_tray_joint
    links:
      torso_tray_link
      
  - name: arm
    joints:
      arm_1_joint
      arm_2_joint
      arm_3_joint
      arm_4_joint
      arm_5_joint
      arm_6_joint
      arm_7_joint
    links:
      arm_0_link
      arm_1_link
      arm_2_link
      arm_3_link
      arm_4_link
      arm_5_link
      arm_6_link
      arm_7_link

  - name: hand
    joints:
      sdh_finger_11_joint
      sdh_finger_12_joint
      sdh_finger_13_joint
      sdh_finger_21_joint
      sdh_finger_22_joint
      sdh_finger_23_joint
      sdh_thumb_2_joint
      sdh_thumb_3_joint
    links:
      sdh_palm_link
      sdh_finger_11_link
      sdh_finger_12_link
      sdh_finger_13_link
      sdh_finger_21_link
      sdh_finger_22_link
      sdh_finger_23_link
      sdh_thumb_1_link
      sdh_thumb_2_link
      sdh_thumb_3_link
      
  #this group is for the experimental cob_object_manipulation    
  - name: end_effector
    links: 
      sdh_palm_link
      sdh_finger_11_link
      sdh_finger_12_link
      sdh_finger_13_link
      sdh_finger_21_link
      sdh_finger_22_link
      sdh_finger_23_link
      sdh_thumb_1_link
      sdh_thumb_2_link
      sdh_thumb_3_link
```

I am currently using the diamondback version.

Someone working previously with this said they had no issues with collisions back in April when they were looking at it....has there been any major changes in planning/collision checking since then?

If there are other configuration files, or launch files that I could include which would be of use, please let me know!  Thanks for your time!

Robert

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10726/ompl-planning-attempts-to-move-through-static-obstacles/) by [Robert](https://answers.ros.org/users/894/robert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without more information (configuration, launch files, etc.), it will be hard to debug this. There are tools coming in Electric that will help you debug this better.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) on 2011-08-08**:
Your launch and yaml files look fine at first glance. I would still suggest waiting for e-turtle - there are graphical tools in e-turtle that will make this much easier, e.g. http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/  Look at the "Automatically Generating Arm Navigation Configurations/Planning Description Configuration Wizard tutorial.

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.ros.org/users/894/robert/) on 2011-08-08**:
ok, i posted some more information.....please let me know if theres something specific that would be of use....